# Is it possible to add or remove columns without a migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-migration

I'm integrating Facebook login for my app. I have a model called "User", and its supposed to have two columns: "provider" and "uid". Everything's fine on development, but I just noticed that on production, "User" doesn't have either column. I tried re-migrating my database on my server, but it didn't help.

So I checked my live code, and "provider" and "uid" are both listed in my schema.db, but they're not mentioned in any of my migration files, on production or development. There aren't any records of any such migration file in any of my commits, either. Somehow they were apparently added to my schema without any migration files. Is this even possible? I mean, if I did write a migration file and just accidentally deleted it later, I think it would still show up in my commits, right? It was so long ago I don't remember what I did.

But anyway, here's my problem: I can't write a migration file adding the columns, because that will cause conflicts on development, and I can't write a migration file removing them and then another file adding them, because then on production the server would be trying to remove columns that don't exist in the first place. Is it possible to add or remove the columns without writing any migration files? Or should I write one removing them, migrate it on development, delete it, write another one adding them, and then migrate that on development and on production?

Since the columns are in my schema.db but not in my actual database, I guess the real question is if migrations edit the schema? Because if so, then I think I could run a down migration and then an up migration on development and production.

Comment: Do you care about the data in those columns in your development environment? You could just delete them by hand, add the missing migration to add them, and run that migration everywhere. BTW, `schema.rb` is based on the current state of your database, that may or may not have anything to do with your migrations.

Comment: What is the name of the table where provider and uid reside? It sounds like "uid" is short for "user_id, which is used in an association to the :users table, because the user id would be just plain id in the :users table. Maybe you can show us the schema?

Comment: @muistooshort How can I delete a column by hand? No, I don't care about the data.

Comment: @user125272 Both columns are supposed to be part of the User table. "uid" represents the User's Facebook ID, if they use Facebook to create an account on my app.

Comment: You could connect to the database using `psql` and say `alter table users drop column provider; alter table users drop column uid;`. Or you could write a migration to remove the columns, run the migration in your development environment, and then delete the migration.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would follow the following quick fix, although it's not that much good, but in case of messy migrations, I do it.

Write a migration that adds columns: `provider` & `uid`. Don't run the migration on your local, and running it won't make any sense. Commit your code, deploy it to production, and run the migration there. Later on, delete the migration, push the code to production. Deleting a migration file doesn't undo the change: it won't remove the two of those columns.

**Gotcha:**
This way, you can amend you changes, but what about a follow developer. Migrations is a way to help maintain the schema consistent for every developer and for every environment out there.

**Nice way of doing it:** You can run `rake db:migrate:status` to list down all the migrations ever written, but not deleted, and you can see how many of them have been up'ed, and how many of them have been down'ed. May be, the migration for adding columns were written in past, but it was up on your local environment, but you not on production.

Remember if when you do `rake db:migrate:status`, it will also list down the version number associated with each migration, so in case if you would like to down a single migration, you can do the following:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=(version_number)
```

And doing `rake db:migrate` will up any migration that was down in past.

Comment: Should I do this even if "provider" and "uid" are currently in my production schema.rb? That won't cause a conflict?

Comment: So you are basically saying that `provider` & `uid` exist in schema on production, but actually are non existent on production?

Comment: Right. I thought that was weird too. When I type in "User" in my rails console, I get back a list of all its columns, but neither "provider" nor "uid" are included. But they're listed in the live schema.rb.

Comment: So if they're already in the schema.rb, and I add them with a migration file, will that cause a conflict?

Comment: Rails is here to rescue us. Run `rake db:schema:load` as it will take the current schema file, and make your database structure look like that.

Comment: Would that delete all my data?